# Laravel VentureCraft/revisionable returned name record with databse

Tags: php, laravel, revision-history, revisionable

Hello in my project I using VentureCraft/revisionable https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable This is addition to recording the history of changes to records in databse. Everything works fine, but when I returned the history on page, the script returns the results in the form of id. This is my table "products" [products_table](http://iv.pl/images/71279002807487439400.png) and this is table "revisions" [revisions_table](http://iv.pl/images/23628904991583704763.png) This table is connected to the tables: articles, users and categories. Now the history change looks like this:

> "User 1 change name article from 2 to 1"

I want to the history change looked like:

> "User JACK change name article from SHOES to BALL"

I try using this [link](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable#identifiablename).

method identifiableName() with file Revisionable.php looks like this:

```
public function identifiableName()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}
```

In model product.php I added:

```
public function identifiableName(){
    return $this->article_name;
}
```

or this:

```
public function identifiableName(){
    return $this->article()->article_name;
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found solution to this problem:
Only just use:
`whereId` or `find` or `faindOrFail` 
example:

```
article::whereId( $hist->old_value )->first()->article_name
```

or

```
article::find( $hist->old_value )->article_name
```

or

```
article::findOrFail( $hist->old_value )->article_name
```

Where `article:name` is name column in articles table.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$history->userResponsible()->first_name
```

like the documentation says

```
@foreach($resource->revisionHistory as $history)
  @if($history->key == 'created_at' && !$history->old_value)
    <li>{{ $history->userResponsible()->first_name }} created this resource at {{ $history->newValue() }}</li>
  @else
    <li>{{ $history->userResponsible()->first_name }} changed {{ $history->fieldName() }} from {{ $history->oldValue() }} to {{ $history->newValue() }}</li>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

or if you want to use it as response api, you can manipulate the response to get their relations

```
$response = $question->revisionHistory->map(function($history) {
            return ['history' => $history, 'users' => $history->userResponsible()];
        });
return response()->json($response);
```